# Custom order by on a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to select 3 specific record and the rest should be random.

**EX:**

```
Database:Records

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want to select 
`2,5,8`.

Comment: What's your input? `2,5,8`?

Comment: `select * from tablename order by 
case 
 when id = 2 then 0 
 when id=5 then 1
 when id = 8 then 2
 else 3
end,id
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of `CASE WHEN` and `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT 
*
FROM table_jess
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(id,'2,5,8') > 0 THEN 0 ELSE id END,id
```

Please check the <kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7131/1/0)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

If you want random result for the rest of the entries then use the following query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM table_jess
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(id,'8,2,5') > 0 THEN 0 ELSE RAND() END,id;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7131/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: thanks! what if i only want to select the 8,2,5 and nothing more

Comment: Then it's too simple. `SELECT 
*
FROM table_jess
WHERE id IN (2,5,8)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not create 2 different queries and combine the result?

Comment: i want to populate it in a listview in VB.net